# Small fonts in minionpro package

Tags: fonts, fontsize, minionpro

I am using `minionpro` package and I need really small fonts.  However, all I get is bunch of the warnings like this one:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <2.75> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 392.
```

Is there anything to do?  Interestingly, `newtx` package didn't have those problems (I have used it before switching to minion).

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. If your problem is with the sans serif cmss then `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` will help. cmss is part of the cm-fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have tried that solution.  Warnings are gone, but fonts are still not small.

Comment: We need a complete example. What do you mean by `not small`?